# How to remove element focus for click event in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

on click(ng-click) of any element we will get blue border by default around that element. I don't want the border so, I tried giving css as follow:

```
    div: focus {
        outline: none;
        border: 0;
    }
```

It will work only on div element, But to reflect on all elements we need to give same css on all elements by doing this we'll increase css code. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Try `*:focus { outline: none; border: 0; }`

Comment: Remove that space between : and focus (.element:focus {})

Comment: Is there any way to do from ng-click rather directly removing all focus. because my Html even have forms where the fields will have focus right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
*:focus {
    outline: none;
    border: 0;
}
```